# How to generalize a function

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to generalize this function to more data, i can duplicate the function and call it GetCumDefaultProportion2 but it's heavy for the program.
How can I do this ?

```
  GetCumDefaultProportion <- function (data){
  # Calcule la proportion cumulée de défaillants F 
  # Input: data.frame avec km et survivor
  # Output: data.frame avec km, survivor et F

  res <- data[order(data$km),]

  lambda <- 1/data$survivor
  H <- cumsum(lambda)
  res$F <- 1 - exp(-H) 

  return(res)
}
```

Comment: Please, show us what `data` looks like and to what kind of dataset you want to generalize your function. (in other words what does change in the new data)

Comment: in this program, data is a dataframe. If i had "data1", "data2", ... how can i calculate "res" whithout repeat several times the function GetCumDefaultProportion.

Comment: If i create a list with "data1", "data2", ...?

Comment: Ok sorry, I misunderstood you. I get it now and I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list named for example "mydfs" :

`lapply(mydfs,GetCumDefaultProportion)` will give you a list of outputs (one for each data.frame).